# How to Query Data from references in AngularFire

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

In the [Denormalizing Data](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html) post, child records can be created by entering an id into the parent record and querying them with code like this:

```
ref.child('/users/{id}/')
```

However, the child method has since been deprecated in AngularFire. When I create records that have a parent, I create the child record and then create the reference in the parent like this:

```
var students = classesRef.child('classes').child(currentClass.$id).child('students');
students.child(studentRef.name()).set(true);
```

When I try to query that record using a function like this:

```
var getStudentsForCurrentClass = function () {
    return $firebaseArray(classesRef.child('classes').child(currentClass.$id).child('students'));
};
```

This is the array that gets returned

[image: The array that gets returned]

This is my Data Structure

[image]

[image]

I get an array full of the references, but no data I can usefully work with. Am I doing this the right way, or should I just assign the classroom id to a variable in the students table and filter by that column?

Answer (score 0):

First thing's first I'm the realest. No but there's a few flaws here.

First of all you should read [this changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/changelog.html) for AngularFire. You will find that both `$firebase` and `$asArray()` has been removed. This has been replaced by `$firebaseObject` and `$firebaseArray`.

Now to query data it is much simpler to just do this, as I do in all my projects:

```
// Get the unique id for the user
var uid = $firebaseAuth(<your-firebase-ref>).$getAuth().uid;

// Specify the path we will be working with
var path = uid + '/programs';

// Get all programs, specified the '/' individually
// to remind you to use it after your reference
var programs = $firebaseArray(<your-firebase-ref> + '/' + path);

// After the programs are done loaded, bind them to the scope
// or if this fails for any reason, set an error message to show the user
programs.$loaded()
  .then(function(data) {
    $scope.programs = data;
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    $scope.error = 'There was an error with the request';
});
```

Another useful function here is to watch for changes at the location for the programs, so if anything changes in the database, it will update the view as well:

```
programs.$watch(function(event) {

  // Fetch the programs again
  programs = $firebaseArray(<your-firebase-ref> + '/' + path);

  programs.$loaded()
    .then(function(data) {
      $scope.programs = data;
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      $scope.error = 'There was an error with the request';
  });
});
```

Comment: That updates my code to the latest version, but I'm still just getting an array of references, not actual records.

Comment: I've updated the code in my original post to use $firebaseArray. What else should I do?

Comment: @JamesStrocel How are you resolving the promise returned by getStudentsForCurrentClass?

Comment: Right now I'm resolving it without the callback from by ClassesService, but the result is pretty much the same.

Comment: `$scope.$watch('currentClass', function () {
      if ($scope.currentClass){
        var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URI);
        $scope.studentList = $firebaseArray(ref.child('classes').child($scope.currentClass.$id).child('students'));

        $scope.studentList.$loaded()
        .then(function(data) {
          $scope.studentList = data;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          $scope.error = 'There was an error with the request';
      });
      console.log($scope.studentList);
     }`

Comment: @JamesStrocel Are you sure you're just getting the keys and not the data? Seems odd that you wouldn't get the data as well.

Comment: I've added screenshots of the array returned and the data structure. I hope that helps!